# How to detect long press on a UICollectionViewCell and and perform an action a the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have a list of images displaying in a UICollectionViewCell. Now I want a way to display an overlay on the image when user long press on the cell. I have been able to place a long press gesture on the cell but unfortunately how to perform the overlay on the cell is where I'm struggling to achieve.

In my cellForItemAt I have this

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reUseMyCellID, for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionCell
cell.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        let directFullPreviewer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: MyCollectionCell(), action: #selector(MyCollectionCell().directFullPreviewLongPressAction))
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(directFullPreviewer)
```

I have this function for the action on LongPressGestureRecognizer in my MyCollectionCell

```
class MyCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    weak var textLabel: UILabel!
    let movieImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView()
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
//        image.image = UIImage(named: "105")
        return image
    }()
    
    let movieOverlay: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.7)
        view.alpha = 0
        return view
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(movieImage)
        movieImage.addSubview(btnRate)
        movieImage.addSubview(movieOverlay)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            movieImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            movieImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            movieImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            movieImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            
            movieOverlay.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.leadingAnchor),
            movieOverlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.topAnchor),
            movieOverlay.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.trailingAnchor),
            movieOverlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: movieImage.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        movieImage.image = nil
    }
    
    func configure(with urlString: String){

        movieImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder"))
        
    }
    
    @objc func directFullPreviewLongPressAction(g: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if g.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began
        {
            
            movieOverlay.alpha = 1
        }
    }
   
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has many issues when creating the long press gesture.

You are setting the target to a new cell instance that is immediately thrown away. Set the target as `cell`, not `MyCollectionCell()`.

You are also using the wrong syntax for the selector. Don't attempt to create a new instance of a cell. Just pass the name of the method `#selector(MyCollectionCell.directFullPreviewLongPressAction)`.

Having said all of that, there is no reason this code should be in the `cellForItemAt` method. You should be creating the long press gesture inside the cell class.

Remove these three lines from `cellForItemAt`:

```
cell.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()
let directFullPreviewer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: MyCollectionCell(), action: #selector(MyCollectionCell().directFullPreviewLongPressAction))
cell.addGestureRecognizer(directFullPreviewer)
```

Then add the following lines inside the `init` of `MyCollectionCell`:

```
let directFullPreviewer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(directFullPreviewLongPressAction))
addGestureRecognizer(directFullPreviewer)
```

Now the cell is fully responsible for setting up and handling the long press gesture.

---

Unrelated to your question, you should know that the line:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

should be:

```
cell.tag = indexPath.item
```

`row` is used for `UITableView`. `item` is used for `UICollectionView`.

But besides that, you really should avoid such code. If your collection view allows cells to be inserted, deleted, and/or reordered, then a cell's tag will no longer represent the `item` you set.

Comment: I noticed actions performed on the cells disappears when you scroll down and scroll up. Is there a way I can persist the action on the cell even if I scroll to the bottom of the collection view and come back up?

Comment: You should post a new question with all relevant details.